# spresense+VSCodeでSDKのalarmの書き込みが出来ない

Tags: spresense, vscode

Spresense開発初心者です。
下記SDKのチュートリアルの2.1. RTC alarm サンプルアプリケーションをVSCで実行しようとしてます。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html

その際に下記の記述があるのですが、どう参考にしてVSCodeでalarmをspresenseに書き込むのか分かりません。

> ###### 2.1.1. ビルド手順
>
> ここではコマンドラインによるビルド手順を示します。
> IDE を使用してビルドする場合、以下に示すコンフィグレーション情報を参考にしてください。

分からないながらも、添付の様にalarmフォルダで、spresenseにビルドと書き込みを行ったのですが、マクロの定義が無くalarmコマンドがspresenseに書き込まれません。
どの様にコンフィグレーションをすればalarmが書き込まれるのか教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 実行画面です]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDKのコンフィグレーション手順
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_sdkのコンフィグレーション](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_sdk%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)

上記ドキュメントを参考に、何かしらアプリケーションコマンドを追加している場合は、

1. アプリケーションフォルダを右クリックして`Spresense: SDKコンフィグ`を開く
2. `新規作成`をクリック
3. `Examples`タブ -> `alarm` を選択して、`OK`をクリックする
4. `保存`をクリックしてコンフィグレーションを保存する
5. アプリケーションフォルダを右クリックして`Spresense: ビルドと書き込み`を実行する

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。下記３．が抜けており、追加したところマクロ解決出来ました。
3.Examplesタブ -> alarm を選択して、OKをクリックする

ただ、下記エラーが発生しておりますが、過去にも似たようなご質問があったみたいなのでそれを見ながら進めてみます。

make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile.unix:236: include/nuttx/version.h] エラー 1
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/c/msys64/home/0000960141/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
make: *** [Makefile:114: all] エラー 2
ターミナル プロセス "c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe '-c', '.vscode/build.sh build'" が終了コード 2 で終了しました。

今後ともよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 検索したのですが、やはり下記エラーが解決できないです  
 
 make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile.unix:236: include/nuttx/version.h] エラー 1 make[1]: ディレクトリ '/c/msys64/home/0000960141/spresense/nuttx' から出ます make: *** [Makefile:114: all] エラー 2 ターミナル プロセス "c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe '-c', '.vscode/build.sh build'" が終了コード 2 で終了しました。